# Need response header cookie with IE object

Tags: vba, vbscript

I need to fetch the response header cookies using IE object from an application that I am trying to access.
For some reason, I cannot using `XMLHTTP` or `WinHttpRequest` as this takes me to authentication and I do not really know how my application is setup based around authentication.

I tried using `cook = IE.Document.cookie` , but all it returns is request header cookies.It does not return response header cookies.

```
  ServerName = "XYZ.com"

  QCServer = "https://" & ServerName & "/qcbin/start_a.jsp"


   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   Dim html As HTMLDocument

   IE.navigate QCServer

   IE.Visible = True


   While IE.Busy

    DoEvents

   Wend

cookiestr=IE.Document.cookie
```

Can someone please guide me on how to get response header cookies using `IE object`?